# How can I change the label text in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, onchange

I have a textbox and a label. If the user wants to change the label text, he/she would have to enter the text in the textbox. How can I update the label text every time a user makes an entry in the textbox on change?

I know it is possible using AJAX with jQuery and PHP. Is there an easier way?
Please let me know. Here is my code and a link: http://jsfiddle.net/uQ54g/1/

```
$('#change1').change(function(){
    var l = $(this).val();
    $('label').replaceWith(l);


});
```

Comment: code in your fiddle is working change is triggered on blur click out side the textbox after entering the value

Comment: Are you wanting to do it after every letter entered or just after the user has completed their changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you have to use `.text` or `.html` to set the text within a label in jquery. Your current code will actually remove the label element and replace with just text. Therefore, it will no longer work if you try to edit the value again. You also may want to add a class or an id to your label because most likely you will have more than one label on a page.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="change1"/><br/>
<label id="test">Hello</label>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#change1').change(function(){
    var l = $(this).val();
    $('#test').text(l);
    // OR $('#test').html(l);
});
```

If you are wanting to change the label after every character entered you will need to use `keyup` instead of `change`.

Here is an updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uQ54g/6/)​

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How easy was that for you to figure out. Im a beginner in JavaScript as you can see. I have another question that you will know how to answer.  I'd like to save those changes for whenever the user logs back in. What would be the best solution to save those changes to the database using the code I have? If it is using the request from jQuery Ajax and PHP, could you guide me through it?

Comment: Post another question with the specifics of what you are trying to do and your current code. It will be easier to understand if I and others can see the big picture. I am sure someone will be able to help you out.

Answer (score 2):

The code in you fiddle is working fine as i mentioned in the comments, or you can use `keyup` like

```
$('#change1').keyup(function(){
var l = $(this).val();
$('label').text(l);
//alert($('#change1').val())
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uQ54g/4/

also note that when you use `replaceWith` it will replace the matched element, in your case it `label` after the change is triggered the `<label>hello</label>` will be replace with `Changed Text` so if you do `$("label")` again it will return you undefined, [**see it for yourself**](http://jsfiddle.net/uQ54g/9/)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('#change1').keyup(function(){
l=$(this).val()
$('label').html(l)
})
```

Comment: `$(label)` will throw an error also the id is `change1` as per the OP's provided markup

Answer (score 1):

use this with jquery library

```
$('#change1').on('keyup',function(){ //Change1 is id of textbox
   $('#label1').html($(this).val()) //label1 is the id of the label
});
$('#change1').blur(function() { //if we copy paste some text into the textbox it will also work if use this blur and trigger function
   $(this).trigger('keyup');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
$('#change1').change(function(item){
     $('label').text(item.target.value);
});
```

Comment: This will replace the label with just text and will no longer work after the first change of the textbox value.